# Material-Table: Change a specific action's colour on click / state change

Tags: reactjs, material-table

How can I style a particular MT action based on a different state?

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
 actions={[
              rowData => {
                const active = rowData && selected && rowData.tableData.id === selected.tableData.id;
                return {
                  icon: 'bug_report',
                  iconProps: { color: active ? 'secondary' : 'primary' },
                  onClick: (event, info) => {
                    setSelected(info);
                  },
                };
              },
]}
```

However, instead of colouring the single selected element, it just stays as `primary` and does nothing. Why? Is it because the actions is rendered for action row and the next row `!==` selected?

Comment: Could you explain or show, where is selected coming from? Are you using the selection feature at options? Also, what do you mean by "based on a different state"? thx

Comment: Sure. Selected is part is just a state within that implementing component and holds the rowData. Basically, if selected (the rowData) is equal to that row with that same rowData it should do something. Like make the icon blue, instead of black, to indicate that this is “active”. Does that make sense? And which selection feature, I haven’t come across this one yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on what I understood, I followed your code and ended up with this:

[image: MT change icon props demo]

```
actions={[
      rowData => {
        let active =
          rowData &&
          clickedRow &&
          rowData.tableData.id === clickedRow.tableData.id;
        return {
          icon: "bug_report",
          tooltip: "Report bug",
          onClick: (event, rowData) => setClicked(rowData),
          iconProps: { color: active ? "primary" : "secondary" }
        };
      }
    ]}
```

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-change-action-iconprops-demo-7yt9o?file=/src/App.js).

I hope this is what you were looking for, if not, I believe that the examples at the official [docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/selection) on Selection feature may help you with this kind of behaviour.

good luck!